# Image height is reset to 0 after upgrading to Vue 3

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have the following image definition.

Template:

```
<img :src="logoSVG" height="150px" alt="logo" />
```

JS:

```
data() {
  return {
    logoSVG: require('./assets/logo.svg')
  }
}
```

This code works well with Vue 2. Note that the height of the image is set directly in the image.

**Problem:** After I upgraded to Vue 3, the images height is set to 0 in the rendered component.

Here is what it generates:

```
<img src="/img/logo.136099f1.svg" height="0" alt="logo">
```

**Question:** How to make Vue 3 correctly render height of an SVG image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to remove `px` from `height="150px"` and keep it like  :

```
<img :src="logoSVG" height="150" alt="logo" />
```

and the data property should be :

```
data() {
  return {
    logoSVG: require('./assets/logo.svg').default 
  }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but what if you were using `%` instead of `px`? 

Comment: Try out `:height="'50%'"`

Answer (score -1):

If you were using `%` of another units, a style tag can be used instead of `width` or `height` attributes. For example, `style="width: 100%"`